# adding security http headers to aws lambda function

Tags: aws-lambda, http-headers, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cloudfront

We have a simple application structure that our ReactJs front-end make request to api gateway which does a proxy-integration with a lambda function. Since our api gateway is passing requests as they are without any modification and do the same when returning responses to customer so the place we are going to add http security headers would be in the lambda function itself. I have done some research on how it can be achived but all the answers I got searching in Google mention lambda@Edge+Cloudfront similar to [this post](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/networking-and-content-delivery/adding-http-security-headers-using-lambdaedge-and-amazon-cloudfront/) which we do not use at all, does it mean we have to change our structure by adding these two things? Thanks.

Comment: if you are intending to use cloudfront+lamba@edge, how are you planning to host your app can you share more info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The article you reference assumes the backend is static (e.g. S3) and cannot set headers. That's why Lambda@Edge is used.

It sounds like your current setup should work without any changes... Did you try adding headers in the code?

I have this code working perfectly for the APIGW + Lambda (proxy integration) combo.

```js
exports.handler = async function (event) {
  var response = {
    statusCode: 200,
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
      'X-My-Header': 'whatever'
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({status: 'OK'}),
  }
  
  return response
}
```

[image]

[Add HSTS header in AWS Lambda](https://www.maxivanov.io/http-strict-transport-security/#implement-in-node.js).

Comment: yes it works, guess I just overthought a simple problem :D